# Why is there an incorrect syntax near varchar

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv

I am reading in a CSV file and then writing to a SQL table. I am creating the table on the fly before writing to it with this code:

```
string exists = null;

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sysobjects where name = '" + tbTable.Text + "'", myConnection);
    exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception exce)
{
    exists = null;
}

if (exists == null)
{
   foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
   {
      if (exists == null)
      {
         SqlCommand createtable = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + tbTable.Text + " (" + dc.ColumnName + " varchar(MAX))", myConnection);
         createtable.ExecuteNonQuery();
         exists = tbTable.Text;
      }
      else
      {
         SqlCommand addcolumn = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + tbTable.Text + " ADD " + dc.ColumnName + " varchar(MAX)", myConnection);
         addcolumn.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }

   using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection))
   {
       try
       {
           bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tbTable.Text;
           bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
           tbTable.Enabled = true;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Program Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
          tbTable.Enabled = true;
       }
    }
 }
```

I keep getting the following error:

> SqlException was unhandled: Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'

On the following lines:

```
SqlCommand addcolumn = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + tbTable.Text + " ADD " + dc.ColumnName + " varchar(MAX)", myConnection);
addcolumn.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

What the code is suppose to do is check if the table exist, if it does and the column doesn't match, add new columns to match the CSV file.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you confirmed what the command evaluates after the text has been concatenated? Have you then run that SQL against your DB to verify it works?

Comment: Why are you catching and eating all the valuable exceptions?

Comment: I would suggest you use parameters instead of string concatenation for you SQL query, then debug your program, grab the query string, and run it in your query tool to see what it's doing.

Comment: I have the same code to read from a DBF and it's working fine.

Comment: What database platform are you using?  Oracle, Sql Server, MySql?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Some of the column name had space which I didn't realize so I added [ and ] for the column name and it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap the column name in quotes, like such:

```
SqlCommand addcolumn = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + tbTable.Text +
               " ADD '" + dc.ColumnName + "' varchar(MAX)", myConnection);
```

Notice the extra single quotes.

Also, concatenating user input (e.g., `tbTable.Text`) in a query is extremely dangerous. You should be using parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Some of the column name had space which I didn't realize so I added `[` and `]` for the column name and it works!

Comment: it's a readonly textbox which is displayed from a file name, so I am not worried at the moment but I do agree with your point. Thank you.